# Load Test : Exception for access denied for agent pc (LoadTestCounterCategoryNotFoundException)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, load-testing

> Exception LoadTestCounterCategoryNotFoundException 1
>   The performance counter category 'Memory' cannot be accessed on computer 'SHIKHA-PC' (Access is denied) ; check that the category and computer names are correct.

I got this error while running a the load test. The test includes 2 agents one on the controller machine from where I run the test, and second on Shikha pc mentionned above.

I am using: Window Server 2008, VS2010. Load test is running on the controller machine.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: This blog explains how to make performance counters available for load tests: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/edglas/archive/2008/11/19/reading-performance-counters-on-vista-and-server-2008-machines.aspx

Answer (score 2):

essentially what is happening is that when the load test controller is asking for an perfmon category from 'SHIKHA-PC' it is getting a timeout. Either that happens because you do not have the permission to access the perfmon settings on that PC (a mix of required user permissions and making sure the [correct port is open](https://serverfault.com/questions/37942/use-perfmon-to-connect-to-a-remote-computer)), or there are simply to many requests for the PC to respond to in time.

I have in the past had some success by using `TypePerf -q -s SHIKA-PC` in a command line session. This "warms up" the performance counters.

Call the Typeperf command from a cmd console on the controller.

For Travis Lingenfelder's blog post on this problem see [here](http://blogs.catapultsystems.com/tlingenfelder/archive/2009/06/18/performance-counters-timeouts-and-load-testing-with-visual-studio-2008.aspx)

Some steps to take:

1. Make sure the account running the Visual Studio load test on the
   controller is a member of the groups "Performance Monitor Users" and "Performance Log Users"
2. Test the port 139 is open on between the controller and SHIKA-PC by calling "Telnet shika-pc 139" from a cmd prompt on the controller.

Comment: Hi Nat ... could u please ans mi some queries i relay get confused doing from long time .. 1. where should i run the command typerperf -q -s shikha-pc you suggest i have done on shikha pc and on server where controller exist i prompt for access denied error ......2)  i have already gone with travis blog its not for vs2010 i can't find VSTestHost.exe file and one more thing what he mentioned should be done on pc(shikha-pc) or server(where controller exist). ....  i have done steps on server but not work   3.) how to manage port you suggest

Comment: Added some explicit steps to take

Answer (score 0):

To add my answer to this old question as I just solved this myself:

Ensure that you are running the Controller process as the correct user:

- Start->Run->services.msc
- Right Click Visual Studio Controller, Properties, Log On tab
- Ensure correct user and password is entered there